Show that there exists a Lebesgue integrable function on $\mathbb{R}^d$ such that $\lim_{k\to\infty} f_k(x)=f(x)$.
Supposed that $\{f_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of Lebesgue integrable function on $\mathbb{R}^d$ satisfying
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}|f_k(x)-f_{k+1}(x)|dx\le 2^{-k}
$$
for every $k\in\mathbb{N}$.
Show that there exists a Lebesgue integrable function on $\mathbb{R}^d$ such that $\lim_{k\to\infty} f_k(x)=f(x)$.

In my proof, I try to use the following Lemma:

If $f_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in measure, then there is a measurable function $f$ such that $f_n\to f$ in measure, and there is a subsequence $f_{n(k)}$ such that $f_{n(k)}$ converges to $f$ $\mu$-a.e.

To prove that $f_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in measure, note that for every $\epsilon>0$, and $m>n \in\mathbb{N}$,
$$
\mu(|f_m-f_n|\ge \epsilon)\le \sum_{k=n}^{m-1}\mu(|f_k-f_{k+1}|\ge \epsilon)\le \epsilon^{-1}\sum_{k=n}^{m-1}2^{-k}\to 0
$$
where we apply Markov's inequality in the last step.
Hence, there is a subsequence $f_{n(k)}$ such that $f_{n(k)}$ converges to $f$ $\mu$-a.e.
Does it make sense? However, how do we show that $f$ is integrable?

You did not prove that the whole sequence $(f_k)$ converges.
Let $g=\sum |f_k-f_{k+1}|$. $g$ is a measurable function with values in $[0,\infty]$. Check using either Monotone Convergence Theorem or Fubini's Theorem that $\int g(x)dx=\sum \int |f_k(x)-f_{k+1}(x)|dx\le \sum \frac 1 {2^{k}}<\infty$. This imples that $g(x) <\infty$ almost everywhere. The $(n-1)-$st partial sum of the (absolutely) convergent series $\sum (f_k-f_{k+1})$  is $f_1-f_{n}$ . It follows that $f_n$ converges a.e. to some measurable function $f$. Now $|f_1-f_n| \leq |f_1-f_2|+|f_2-f_3|+\cdots +|f_{n-1}-f_n|\leq g$ and for each $n$. Taking limit as $ n \to \infty$ we get $|f_1-f|\leq g$. It follows that $\int |f|\leq \int |f_1|+\int g <\infty$.
